# Combining an output of multiple lists into one list (Python)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a simple loop that outputs random hashes.

```
    import bcrypt
    from Crypto.Random import random

    def PRG():
        return random.randint(1,100000)

    def p():
        return [str(bcrypt.gensalt(PRG()))]

    for i in range(1,6):
        print(list(p()))
```

This returns:

```
    ['$2a$31$GyPdJsZDHSdfFlRqrtkuWO']
    ['$2a$31$r.d6EnQelVkLRkhgLT/dDe']
    ['$2a$31$TAFTlk09m1mZTrZjxqzxGu']
    ['$2a$31$dEC9aKcvz47tqtDH6Ge5XO']
    ['$2a$31$f3Qt6P9zXt7D2JCntGWCOu']
```

I'd like to combine these lists into one list. I know I could just add the lists together with another line of code once I know the output, but doing that with, say, 100 different lists is impractical. If someone could please help me I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: The loop in `p` doesn't make sense as the first iteration will `return`. Also, that function contains a syntax error (missing colon). Did you mean `def p(): return [str(bcrypt.gensalt(PRG())) for _ in xrange(5)]`?

Comment: I just realized that the loop in p() was redundant, as you said and I forgot the colon on p() when defining it when copying it here. But thank you, I deleted my last two lines and amended p() and it works as I want it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making `p()` return just a single element, and using a list comprehension to build the final list:

```
def p():
    return str(bcrypt.gensalt(PRG()))

list_of_salts = [p() for _ in range(1,6)]
```